# OpenStreetMap add marker to Nutiteq MapView with custom Xfermode

Tags: android, canvas, openstreetmap, nutiteq, xfermode

I need to put some markers on top of a Nutiteq MapView. In order to create these markers I create a bitmap with a semi-transparent circle.

```
int size = (int)(30*mDisplayMetrics.density);
Bitmap androidMarkerBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.argb(150, 255, 0, 0));

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(androidMarkerBitmap);
canvas.drawCircle(size / 2, size / 2, size / 2, paint);
com.nutiteq.graphics.Bitmap markerBitmap = BitmapUtils.createBitmapFromAndroidBitmap(androidMarkerBitmap);
androidMarkerBitmap.recycle();
```

Each marker has the same bitmap. The problem is the transparency of the bitmap (as you can see alpha is not 0). When I add many markers all the bitmaps are simply ADDED one over the another... The problem is that I do not want the "add" effect for transparency, but instead I need to obtain the "darken" one.

[image]
<sub>(source: [csdn.net](http://img.blog.csdn.net/20140426213750328?watermark/2/text/aHR0cDovL2Jsb2cuY3Nkbi5uZXQvbG1qNjIzNTY1Nzkx/font/5a6L5L2T/fontsize/400/fill/I0JBQkFCMA==/dissolve/70/gravity/Center))</sub>

Is there a way to change the default Xfermode used when mapView draws markers on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such option in Nutiteq SDK. The effect you describe would require rendering markers to a separate surface (with 'darken' effect) and then layering the rendered surface (with markers) atop of other layers. Such functionality is pretty expensive and is not implemented in the SDK.